# Date Zero Validation In Java

Tags: java, date

I have a method taking `Date field` as a input parameter.

```
public static String formatDate(Date inputDate) {
    // if user send the date with inputDate= new Date(00000000) or new Date(0L) because it is Java default date.
    I have to send the exception error with message Invalid date.
}
```

What I did is something as below, But I am unable to get the error while passing the invalid date of zero count-from-epoch like "new Date( 0L )" as inputDate parameter.

```
public static String formatDate(Date inputDate) {
    if (null == inputDate)
        throw new FieldFormatException("Empty date field.");

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        return formatter.format(inputDate);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new FieldFormatException("Exception in formatting date field." + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: "if user send the date with inputDate= 00000000" makes no sense, as `inputDate` is a `Date`, not a `String`.

Comment: What I mean is `new Date(0L)` or 8 length 0 values, What I need is Invalid date rather than converting to `19700101`.

Comment: Right, that was *very, very* unclear. Why not just call `Date.getTime()` and see whether that returns 0?

Comment: Additionally the "which is yyyyMMdd format" in your comment in the code is very unclear. A `Date` value doesn't have a format.

Comment: Calling `new Date(0L)` or `Date(00000000L)` is the same thing - you're passing the number zero to [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) - which means you're creating a date which is equivalent to zero milliseconds since epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`), which is the epoch itself. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
if (inputDate == null || inputDate.getTime() == 0L)
```

That will detect if `inputDate` is null or represents the Unix epoch.

As noted in the comments though:

- Rejecting a single value is kinda dangerous - why is `new Date(0)` "wrong" but `new Date(1)` "right"?
- This prevents you accepting *legitimate* input that happens to be the Unix epoch

Comment: I feel like it's worth noting that this has the very horrible smell of only checking for one date value and could be easily circumvented by just `new Date(1)`. When I get questions like this from a developer I usually have to go back and ask "why do you only care about that one value?" and the answer is almost always that they care about more than that one value.

Comment: What happen if some people  have exactly epoch date as a input `1970-01-01T00:00Z`? I will get `getTime()` as a zero and I am risking of losing data.

Comment: @RameshKC: I answered your requirement. If your requirement doesn't make sense, you need to question that. You wanted to explicitly reject 1970-01-01T00:00Z - you can't have it both ways. I agree with gnomed's concern, btw.

Comment: What I am curious is if some system have default date as zero. while validating I have to discard those zeros date, that is what I am trying to achieve and  formatting in yyyyMMdd if date is not zero.

Comment: @RameshKC: Sorry, I'm afraid that comment makes no sense to me at all... and fundamentally, just because a value happens to be a default doesn't mean it can't *also* be real data.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted Answer by Skeet is correct.

## tl;dr

```
input.equals( Instant.EPOCH )
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now supplanted by the java.time classes.

The `Instant` class takes the place  of `Date` as a moment on the timeline in UTC but with a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

You can convert when interfacing with legacy code not yet updated to java.time classes. To convert, call new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myDate.toInstant() ;
```

Check for null.

```
if ( null == input ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Received invalid input: null." ) ;
}
```

Check for that count-from-epoch value zero that seems to be of special concern to you. The `Instant` class has a constant for that, for a count of zero nanoseconds from the epoch reference date-time used by Unix and Java: first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
if ( input.equals( Instant.EPOCH ) ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Received invalid input: Instant.EPOCH. Input must be later than 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z." ) ;
}
```

You might want to check for recent date-time values, if required by your business rules.

```
if ( input.isBefore( Instant.now() ) ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Received invalid input. Input must not be in the past." ) ;
}
```

When generating a string take into account time zone. For any given moment, the date and the time-of-day vary around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Your desired format happens to be the "basic" version of a standard ISO 8601 format. This format is predefined as a constant: [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```